# Is is possible for customer reviews to show in all countries?

Tags: app-store

I have an English-only iOS app listed in App Store for all countries. However, it seems that customer reviews only get displayed to customers who are also in that country. For example, US users do not see reviews written by users in New Zealand or Ireland, etc. Is there any way that I as a developer can set up my app such that US users can see customer reviews written by people in other countries (perhaps at least if they're written in English) ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but the answer is simple:  it's not possible at all on the AppStore. There is no any connection between the countries, not in reviews, ratings and in any other parameters.

Actually the review system is very mysterious phenomenon with secrets and traps and Apple rules are very strict in this context. Even the suspicion of manipulation could lead to deletion of the app from the AppStore forever so avoid any kind of direct or indirect influence intentionally or not.